# Python send non-ascii email via sendmail

Tags: python-3.x, email, sendmail

I wrote a Python based [postforward.py script](https://github.com/gldecurtins/postforward). The script rewrites the Return-Path using SRS so that the email forwarding works without being blocked. Overall the script works, but it fails forwarding non-ascii content to sendmail.

If I want to forward the following Email:

```
Return-Path: <from@elpmaxe.com>
Delivered-To: to@example.com
Received: from example.com
    by example.com with LMTP
    (envelope-from <to@example.com>)
    for <to@example.com>; Sat, 04 Feb 2023 16:31:01 +0100
From: From <from@elpmaxe.com>
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Mime-Version: 1.0 (Mac OS X Mail 16.0 \(3731.400.51.1.1\))
Subject: Test subject
Message-Id: <11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555@example.com>
Date: Sat, 4 Feb 2023 16:30:46 +0100
To: To <to@example.com>

Test Body
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-ÄÖÜ
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-äöü
```

I reduced my postforward.py script to the minimum to replicate the issue:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from email.parser import Parser
from email.policy import default
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

message = Parser(policy=default).parsestr(sys.stdin.read())
sendmailArgs = ["sendmail", "-i", "-f", SRSReturnPath, TO]
sendmail = Popen(sendmailArgs, stdin=PIPE)
sendmail.communicate(message.as_bytes())
```

I get the following error:

```
gldecurtins@gians-mac-mini-1 postforward % python3 test.py < Test\ subject\ utf-8.eml                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gldecurtins/GitHub/postforward/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(message.as_bytes())
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/message.py", line 208, in as_bytes
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 116, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 181, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 218, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 436, in _handle_text
    super(BytesGenerator,self)._handle_text(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 253, in _handle_text
    self._write_lines(payload)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 155, in _write_lines
    self.write(line)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/email/generator.py", line 410, in write
    self._fp.write(s.encode('ascii', 'surrogateescape'))
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 27-29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any recommendations on how to handle UTF-8 content? I think I have to use as_bytes(), but this method doesn't seem to support UTF-8.